# Why TypeScript infers never to this generic type argument?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I'm working on a Table and I've created `InferColumnUtils` utility type to allow for some specific styling in the column definition and a format function that will receive the data for each cell and format it.

```
interface Column<I, K extends keyof I> {
  id: K;
  label: string;
  format: (value: I[K]) => ReactNode;
}

type InferColumnUtils<I extends Record<string, unknown>> = NonNullable<
  {
    [_K in keyof I]: Column<I, _K>;
  }[keyof I]
>;
```

The `InferColumnUtils` type works correctly when declaring the columns, correctly inferring the right type to `format` argument.

The issue comes when I want to use the format function inside of a map, TypeScript infers `never` as the `column.format` arg type.

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

```
// Generated type
export type Order = {
  id: string;
  number: number;
  paymentInformation?: 'AUTHORIZED' | 'EXPIRED' | 'PENDING';
  lineItems: Array<Record<string, number>>;
};

interface Column<I, K extends keyof I> {
  id: K;
  label: string;
  format: (value: I[K]) => string;
}

type InferColumnUtils<I extends Record<string, unknown>> = NonNullable<
  {
    [_K in keyof I]: Column<I, _K>;
  }[keyof I]
>;

const columns: readonly InferColumnUtils<Order>[] = [
  {
    id: 'paymentInformation',
    label: 'Payment Status',
    format: (value) => (!value ? 'NO STATUS' : value),
  },
  {
    id: 'id',
    label: 'Order Id',
    format: (value) => `Order #${value}`,
  },
  {
    id: 'lineItems',
    label: 'Items',
    format: (value) => value.length.toString(),
  },
];

const orders: Order[] = [
  {
    id: 'foo',
    paymentInformation: 'AUTHORIZED',
    lineItems: [],
    number: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 'bar',
    paymentInformation: 'PENDING',
    lineItems: [],
    number: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 'baz',
    paymentInformation: 'EXPIRED',
    lineItems: [],
    number: 3,
  },
];

const createCells = () =>
  orders.map((order) =>
    columns.map((column) => column.format(order[column.id]))
  );

createCells()
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-3dnwic?file=index.tsx)

The only way I've managed to infer the right type to the format argument is through the `formatWithType` typeguard but it doesn't seem like a clean solution.

```
// TypeScript complains otherwise, checking the id TS understands what type argument we can pass to column.format
export const formatWithType = (
  order: Order,
  column: InferColumnUtils<Order>
) => {
  const { id, format } = column;

  switch (id) {
    case 'paymentInformation':
      return format(order[id]);
    case 'id':
      return format(order[id]);
    case 'lineItems':
      return format(order[id]);
    case 'number':
      return format(order[id]);
  }
};

const createCells = () =>
  orders.map((order) => columns.map((column) => formatWithType(order, column)));
```

I would expect the format function argument type to be properly typed.

Comment: If you don't get engagement here I'd be happy to look again if you manage to remove the dependency on react (I don't know enough about react to contribute here.) In any case, good luck!

Comment: @jcalz sure, I hope the Minimal Reproducible Example is more accessible now. Thank You!

Comment: Looks like your problem is [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended approach is [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). Your code is very close to the version that works, which looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPJxqN). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It solves the issue, thank You!

I don't quite understand why it works, I thought that `[_K in keyof I]` would have the same result of passing a second `K` argument as `keyof Order`.

Comment: I will write up an answer explaining when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're having is that your `InferColumnUtils<Order>` is a plain [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and so inside the callback to `columns.map`, the expression

```
column.format(order[column.id])
```

can only be seen as safe if you track the *identity* of `column` across both its appearances.  But the compiler doesn't do that, it only looks at the *type*.  Imagine you had `column1` and `column2`, both of type `InferColumnUtils<Order>`.  Then the expression

```
column1.format(order[column2.id])
```

wouldn't be safe, right? In general `column1` and `column2` might represent different members of the union, and you'd expect exactly the error you're seeing.  `column1.format` is a union of functions, and `order[column2.id]` is a union of arguments, but it might not be the right argument for the function.

And since the compiler can't tell the difference between this code and yours, you get the error regardless. Even though it's safe. I call this problem TypeScript's lack of support for *correlated unions* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

---

Luckily there is a recommended approach that does work, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The idea is to switch away from specific union types and toward [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a union.  You can represent your operations in terms of a "base" interface and generic [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that type or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) over that type.

Your code is already quite close to that version, so the refactoring is fairly minor. First we have to change your `InferColumnUtils<Order>` union, which is already a *distributive object type* (as coined in ms/TS#47109) into a -generic- version in the key:

```
type InferColumnUtils<
    I extends Record<string, unknown>,
    K extends keyof I = keyof I
> = NonNullable<
    { [P in K]: Column<I, P>; }[K]
>;
```

If you write `InferColumnUtils<I>` without a second type argument, it [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to your version.  But now if you *provide* a `K` argument, the compiler will see this as being *generic* in `K`, which we'll need.

The callback to `columns.map` also needs to be generic in the key `K`:

```
const createCells = () => orders.map((order) =>
    columns.map(<K extends keyof Order>(
        column: InferColumnUtils<Order, K>
    ) => column.format(order[column.id])) // okay
);
```

That now compiles.  Instead of `column` being considered a plain union, it's a generic distributive type `InferColumnUtils<Order, K>`.  So `column.format()` is no longer seen as a union of functions, it's seen as a single function of type `(value: Order[K]) => string`.  And `column.id` is seen as a single key of type `K`, so `order[column.id]` is a single argument of type `Order[K]`.  It's the identical type that the function wants, so it succeeds.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&install-plugin=typescript-playground-link-shortener#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDyUAmwpwLxwDeAUHGXAJaYBccAzjFBQHYDmA3KecwK4C2AIxy1egnJ3JwwAQ0R9gzGAElmAM2h9pMChGYB+WgHIAggFUAKgAk0AJSUAtAKIARQ3AA+cQ44AaABSUbFzdPQz9HADlnJQiAcUMJcgAbFmAlGGA+OlpjKChZAB4bYABjaEwChiY2ABo4USEoAD4mzgBfTmIWDKhVaRLUAGEIJP5mAqU6gGk4UAzmTDo4AGtgRAhVOCUmoi4yKlopxLIk6SEk2iqWDj24dShNGFoACgA3aVHgWiUAbSmAXQAlPgdlc2O1iMQkCgtmocMNRnxmKZtEk6AVbkpZiB5os4MUylhKoxrnUeMxlswIAB3ZhNGq3GZzBR41brTZYghsjZbYg7AgRXQRHhJU4CJLADGSQhwH5+SjMOAA2gIsYTOp+VpwNp-f58zplZgMOBlRFG2hQYDSTC6JKIWGqeEjMYoihogoYbDNH7-fCy24kSSSA5eGRyBTKNQaLQ6ZiGBlB5JnYAXLx+WTyRRwADKMC0PDo8duknujxe70+wLwO2eAEIKzxUHovBE0DnzMZzKZs25aA3gICE+Q2kOyIHE5QaF4qEWJ3AxSmjJ6cFtMLOJ6WtOWPo2qzsAAbL3AAYgAJIR+2196PtTfx4mQ4YUsw0hksuvEwvU4Z0plCzeS2jJ44DeHcBxBOB+wAOglNgYAACygmAIFzapWGeQdbhHYh-gNXRjXKHBsnQLAcB9P0fgDYtyEfdQIA-IMw0zSNN20XQjDMKxbAcYIAOSVJfyyWgfT4sgGmEOAAEYb2w6VqP2KdDAEaQoAYyQmIjFRWNjIxwiiGJ4lE+cBLfYiRPk+p+EaWgACYZLvCzH2UgAvNTyA0xQtKAnSvF8AIglcIzn1fP9hP+IzxKgWgAGZ7JwvCjXgEpLS0YBBhTNE-QwiDCKgOgoM0MBnmeXK91uU0xnywrngKJkcRZJZuU2I8mmeCyKqRb44SgVUkVdd0j2mJpbj3E1nSRKDWJK0ioB+DrmCgqggUBYhAU4AB6daQLAKAIBQWBEGBXrxkGpUmkmoDt0+Wgj11UawVYYhNu23b9qQI7xpOmahsWqc6txRq1h5I9iGSq0MnS0U6Aw4ggA)

Comment: Thank You for the detailed explanation, this is very interesting and gives a good insight of how the compiler reasons.

I see you're an ambassador for this specific issue, thank you for your commitment to make TS more intuitive!